# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError: (Class).(Method)()V

Tags: java, c, gcc, dll, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI in my final project for my Intro to CS class. I'm almost able to get it working, but have an error that's stumped me the entire last weekend. I've looked around in many places, but haven't been able to fix.

The error I'm getting: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JNI_Functions.dllHello()V

My code:

```
////////////////////////
// JNI_Functions.c

    #include "JNI_Functions.h"
    #include <jni.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNI_1Functions_dllHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        printf("This was sent from the DLL\n");
        return;
    }

///////////////////////
// JNI_Functions.h

    /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
    #include <jni.h>
    /* Header for class JNI_Functions */

    #ifndef _Included_JNI_Functions
    #define _Included_JNI_Functions
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    /*
     * Class:     JNI_Functions
     * Method:    dllHello
     * Signature: ()V
     */

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNI_1Functions_dllHello
      (JNIEnv *, jobject);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
    #endif

//////////////////// JAVA ///////////////////
// Entry.java
    public class Entry {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
    //          JNI_Functions jni = new JNI_Functions();
    //          jni.dllHello();
                new JNI_Functions().dllHello();
            } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't call native function.\n" + e);
            }
        }
    }

///////////////////////
// JNI_Functions.java


public class JNI_Functions {
    public JNI_Functions() {
        System.loadLibrary("JNI_Functions");
        System.out.println("Loaded JNI_Functions.dll");
    }

    // Prints out a simple hello world from the dll
    public native void dllHello();
}
```

I'm using Code::Blocks to compile, here's the output if needed:

```
-------------- Build: Release in JNI_Functions (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -O2 -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at -ID:\JNITest -c D:\JNI_Functions\JNI_Functions.c -o obj\Release\JNI_Functions.o
mingw32-g++.exe -shared -Wl,--output-def=bin\Release\libJNI_Functions.def -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Release\libJNI_Functions.a -Wl,--dll  obj\Release\JNI_Functions.o  -o bin\Release\JNI_Functions.dll -s  
Output file is bin\Release\JNI_Functions.dll with size 9.00 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 9 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 9 second(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class or method name contains an underscore, it becomes `_1` in C, not `_`. This is so that `JNI_Functions.method` and `JNI.Functions_method` don't have the same C names.

See Table 2-1 in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html.

In your case, the C function should be called `Java_JNI_1Functions_dllHello`.

Comment: It was that originally, but I had seen someone who had fixed their issue by doing that. I forgot to change it back I guess. Still doesn't work however.